# C# integral types inconsistency

Tags: c#, integral

I just started reading up on the C# language, and one of the first sections in my reading material is, naturally, variables and types.

In short order I came across the integral types table, which listed *`sbyte`*, *`byte`*, *`short`*, *`ushort`*, *`int`*, *`uint`*, *`long`*, *`ulong`* and *`char`*.
The exception to the pairing here is *`char`*, so let's disregard it and have a look at the others.

The first pair, *`byte`*, prefixes the signed version with an "s", and leaves the unsigned version without a prefix. But for all the other pairs, the relation is reversed... the signed version is without prefix and the unsigned has a "u" prefix.

Is there a reason for this that I should be aware of, or is this just a design quirk?

Link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx

Comment: FYI, this was a hotly contested point during the initial design of the framework, back in the late 1990's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bytes are conventionally treated as a pattern of bits rather than a normal number, and the "standard" values for a byte are 0 to 255. The signed version of byte is the abnormal case, with values treated as -128 to 127.

For all other numeric types the "standard" values are signed, as this tallies with our day-to-day intuitions about numbers (ie, that they can be negative as well as positive). For numeric types, the unsigned versions are the abnormal case.

(I don't think that I've *ever* used `sbyte` in any real-world code, and I use `int`, `long` etc much more often than I use their unsigned counterparts.)

Comment: Sounds logical I suppose. :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that `byte` is probably much more common to be used as an *unsigned type* rather than a *signed type*.